# How to pull all Meetup interest tags as autocomplete tags for a site?

Tags: autocomplete, meetup

I have found the API and categories, http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/2/categories/. However I am not sure how to get all the interests themselves. The most categories I could get was 36 or so. I know however that the site has maybe a thousand or so individual interests, and I would like the interests themselves, which are within the categories (assumedly.) The site has a built in console, so if anyone can tell how to get the interest list, that would be great (as in link posted above.)

I would also like if the list I store on my app would be auto-updated as the meetup list is also updated, but if not then that is fine. Just a +1, whatever I can get.

For example, Meetup allows "Finance" as category, then "stocks" or "Bitcoin" as category. I am hoping to use the list so that users of another app can't input made-up/inappropriate tags. So the meetup one would be great, or another list I suppose.

Once I have a list, I can use something like the jquery token fields gem or chosen gem, as I learned from Railscasts. In those two examples, there was a list that enabled the autocomplete for tokens. I want that exact thing, but to get them from Meetup interests. http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised

I am using Rails 4, Heroku, and Postgres.